# vue run method after all child component rendered

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of messages. parent component is responsible to show messages. I want to scroll to first unread message when all message components have been mounted. messages are rendered by `v-for`.

```html
<div v-for="msg in messages" :key="msg.id">
  <message :text="msg.text"></message>
</div>
```

`messages` is prop of parent component and it is an array. my app have multiple room. user can move between room. after room changed and new messages mounted, parent should scroll to first unread message.

I try `watch`ing room change and use `this.$nextTick` but when `$nextTick`'s callback execute messages are not changed.

I also try this but it is only for one message and is not related to room change :(

```html
<div v-for="msg in messages" :key="msg.id">
  <message :text="msg.text" @hook:mounted="mounted"></message>
</div>
```

Comment: `@hook:mounted` is a hack, children may have their own children and so on, not to mention that mounted != fully rendered. Consider explaining your case. This is most likely XY problem that should be solved in another way.

Comment: I know that children has not their own children

Comment: Children are already mounted when parent's mounted hook runs.

Comment: `arr` can change at runtime and I want to run method again after all new child mounted. what about this?

Comment: Then back to step one, this is a problem that needs to solved in more appropriate way. You didn't specify what you need this for.

Comment: I add lots of detail :)

Comment: I see. This is the case for nextTick. `this.messages = ...; this.$nextTick(() => { /* all message are supposed to be mounted at this time */ })`.  If this is not so in your case, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. This is supposed to work only if comps aren't rendered asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

`onMounted` hook is triggered when before rendering. The DOM elements will probably be unavailable due to asynchronous rendering.

You might want to use `onUpdated` hook. It's triggered after rendering. Also it is synchronized with child components. "A parent component's updated hook is called after that of its child components."

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onupdated